# How to tell if a key has been released in Love2d

Tags: lua, love2d

I want to add an ability in my game where if you hold <kbd>t</kbd> then the enemies are slowed down. l`ove.keyboard.isDown` won't let me put the enemies back to their original speed once the <kbd>t</kbd> key has been released. Is their another way I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`love.keyreleased`](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.keyreleased).

Note that unlike `love.keyboard.isDown`, it's a callback function. Use it to register the action when the key <kbd>t</kbd> is released.

Comment: How would I make it so I can only use the ability once? @Yu Hao

Comment: @BenHarvey - Replace "escape" with "t" in the [example](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.keyreleased)

Answer (score 1):

Using `love.keyboard.isDown` will let you put their original speed back if you check when it's `false`, like so:

```
if love.keyboard.isDown('t') then
    enemy_speed = 15
else
    enemy_speed = 30 -- 't' key has been released
end
```

but there is an another way to do this. Use `love.keypressed` and `love.keyreleased`, like so:

```
function love.keypressed(key)
    if key == 't' then
        enemy_speed = 15
    end
end

function love.keyreleased(key)
    if key == 't' then
        enemy_speed = 30 -- 't' key has been released
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand, love.keyboard.isDown("t") is for to the love.update() function, and it will just repeat the function no matter what. so in this case create a function like this in your main.lua file:

```
function love.keypressed(k)
    if k == "t" then
        // Code goes in here
    end
end
```

like this, it should activate once the key is pressed.